# Converting a degree slope raster to a percent slope raster, without a DEM, using raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, raster-calculator, slope

I've been given a raster of degree slope which I need to convert to percent slope. As the original DEM is not available and those who provided the raster want me to work with this one, I have to convert the degrees to percent. I've attempted to do this with raster calculator, in ArcMap, with the formula (Tan("Degrees"))*100 but this returns nonsensical values with 9+ digits and positive and negative values.

I imagine this is simple but I am doing something incorrectly. Am I missing something or is the wrong syntax? How do I properly convert a degree slope raster to percent slope raster?

Comment: So a 45° slope is a 50% slope, right? So wouldn't the formula be `percent = (degrees/9.0) * 10.0`?

Comment: @Vince, I think 45 degrees is 100% slope! https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022558

Comment: You need Tan(3.141593/180*degrees))*100

Comment: @fatih_dur Doh! Maybe I shouldn't comment while sleepy.

Comment: @FelixIP Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took @FelixIP's advice and used the formula Tan(3.141593/180*degrees))*100. This correctly converts degree slope raster values to percent slope values.